# 3D log density plot in ParaView

Tags: visualization, paraview

I have a .csv file of thousands of (x,y,z) point particles that I would like to visualize in ParaView. I am able to plot a 3D scatterplot using the TableToPoints, and by decreasing point opacity I can see some substructure in the particles' arrangement.

I'm looking for a better option to easily see different regions where particles are clustered or sparse. Is there a 3D density plotting option in ParaView (preferably using a log scale for density). i.e. a 3D histogram where I can see regions of high and low particle density?

Comment: You can create histograms of the coordinates, for example.